# dispay video in jsp website

Tags: jsp, video, youtube

hi i am creating a website as **online audition** for university.here clients can upload their performing videos on youtube.

```
So my question is how can i display those specific videos on my web page as admin should see it and be able to comment also? 
Is there anything like description or trend with help of which i can get those videos only which are uploded by my clients?
and i want to get the path of the videos so as i can just call them in  iframe?
```

Comment: Why not have your clients upload their video to youtube and then have them leave their video id on your web page.

Comment: @rickz i also thought of something same. Can u give me any link where i can get more details as how to leave video id and fetch it on a webpage?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a JSP. Please bear in mind that this is just a demonstration. You need to rewrite it. As I have posted it, the data will be lost when the web server is restarted. You should put the data in your database or in a file.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<iframe id="videoFrame" width="420" height="345">
</iframe><br/><br/>
Watch a video:
<%
   HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap)application.getAttribute("map");
   if(map == null){
        map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        application.setAttribute("map", map);
   } 
   String id = request.getParameter("vid");
   String title = request.getParameter("title");
   if(id != null && !"".equals(id.trim()) 
         && title != null && !"".equals(title.trim()))map.put(id.trim(),title.trim());
   Iterator<String> iter = map.keySet().iterator();
   while(iter.hasNext()){
       String i = iter.next();
       String t = map.get(i);
       out.print("<a href='?vid=" + i + "&title=" + t + "' >" + t + "</a> ");
   }
%>
  <form>
    Add your video:
    id<input name="vid" type="text" />  
    title<input name="title" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
<script>
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/${param.vid}";
document.getElementById("videoFrame").src = url;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for help but i am getting following errors                    An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file:**/***
HashMap cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: I added the import. I posted the easiest code to do this. You should read at https://developers.google.com/youtube/  for more complete implementation. Also, you should consider security. Your users could enter malicious code as input.